# hdfs namenode -format error (no such file or directory)

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

Trying to get hadoop 2.3.0 running locally on my ubuntu machine, attempting to format the hdfs namenode, I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs:
line 34:
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/../libexec/hdfs-config.sh:
No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs:
line 204: exec: : not found
```

I think I have edited all the required files (`bashrc`, `hadoop-env.sh`, `core-site.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`).

Any help?

Comment: Does this directory exist? `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the profile to set the home variables for Hadoop and Java.

## sudo vi .bashrc

Set the hadoop home:

Add following  after ("if [-f /etc/bash_completion] && lshopt -0q posix; then ./etc/bashcompletion fi")

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/hduser/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hduser/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin
```

Save and exit [esc+:wq]

Edit the hadoop-env.sh by

## sudo vi /home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

Add the following line,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Now you can able to format the namenode.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have environment variable pointing to HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR

Add it to ~/.bashrc

```
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/libexec
```