# hadoop 2.7.3 HDFS Namenode -format No Such FIle or Directory error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to install Hadoop 2.7.3 on a Lubuntu box using [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) tutorial. I'm at the point where it's time to format the HDFS using the namenode -format command. Whenever I do though I get this error:

```
    HadoopBot@hadoopmaster-MS-7756:~/Hadoop/hadoop/bin$ /home/HadoopBot/Hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format
    /home/HadoopBot/Hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /home/HadoopBot/Hadoop/hadoop/bin/$/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I've made all the edits described in the tutorial as well as the ones suggested in the top answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855446/hdfs-namenode-format-error-no-such-file-or-directory/) topic. I've also set my $JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment to match hadoop-env.sh

EDIT: Here's a Pastebin link to the .bashrc file. Most of the relevant info should be at the bottom though I've included the whole thing just in case. http://pastebin.com/w4JMhRZ0

Comment: Do you have java installed in :
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java?

And do your user have acces to this folder?

Comment: Can you show your bashrc file?

Comment: Update your post with .bashrc

Comment: I added a link to my bashrc

Comment: Also Luis all my users have access to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Answer (score 1):

I don't have power to comment, but looking at at your .bashrc file, the last line has wrong import for JAVA_HOME.
It should be:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

and not

```
export JAVA_HOME =usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

where you have missed to add the root. If this too doesn't solve your problem, then once again go through hadoop_env.sh and ensure that you have not mistakenly added an extra JAVA_HOME line which looks the case.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message,

> line 304:
>   /home/HadoopBot/Hadoop/hadoop/bin/$/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java:
>   No such file or directory

Hadoop is looking at a malformed JAVA_HOME variable. The variable points to an non-existent path **/home/HadoopBot/Hadoop/hadoop/bin/$/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/**. Search for all the JAVA_HOME entries made during the installation and update with correct value.

Then format the namenode and start the services.